# Enums as Map keys don't work in Batchable

Tags: apex, batch, map, platform-bug, enum

I'm running into some weird behavior when using an Enum as a Key in a map.  This same code works fine in other contexts, but not when in batch.

I have an Enum to represent currency types:

```
   public enum CurrencyType {
       USD, AUD, GBP, CAD
   }
```

In an exchange client, I have a `Map<CurrencyType, Decimal>`.  However, when I try to `get` a value using an Enum, it's returning null.

```
  private Map<CurrencyType, Decimal> exchangeRates;

   /**
     * Returns the exchange rate for any given currency vs the base
     * @param  currencyType The currency to get the exchange rate for
     * @return              The Exchange Rate for given currency
     */
  public Decimal getExchangeRate(CurrencyType currencyType){
        System.debug(currencyType);  //GBP
        System.debug(exchangeRates); //{USD=1.0, AUD=1.3184, CAD=1.3065, GBP=0.79164}
        System.debug(exchangeRates.containsKey(currencyType)); //false

        for(CurrencyType ct : exchangeRates.keySet()){
            System.debug(ct); //when == GBP
            system.debug(ct == currencyType); //true
            System.debug(ct.hashCode()); //127990640
            System.debug(currencyType.hashCode()); //608648681
        }

        return exchangeRates.get(currencyType); //returns null
   }
```

### UPDATE:

Here is the Raw Debug Statements so you can see everything is populated properly:

```
12:50:53.0 (19696843)|USER_DEBUG|[55]|DEBUG|~Getting Exchange Rates~
12:50:53.0 (19711834)|USER_DEBUG|[56]|DEBUG|GBP
12:50:53.0 (19752692)|USER_DEBUG|[57]|DEBUG|{USD=1.0, AUD=1.3184, CAD=1.3065, GBP=0.79164}
12:50:53.0 (19786841)|USER_DEBUG|[58]|DEBUG|false
12:50:53.0 (19805826)|USER_DEBUG|[59]|DEBUG|608648681
12:50:53.0 (19815542)|USER_DEBUG|[60]|DEBUG|~Testing vs Keyset~
12:50:53.0 (19879783)|USER_DEBUG|[62]|DEBUG|USD
12:50:53.0 (19912155)|USER_DEBUG|[63]|DEBUG|false
12:50:53.0 (19930846)|USER_DEBUG|[64]|DEBUG|70283834
12:50:53.0 (19945440)|USER_DEBUG|[65]|DEBUG|608648681
12:50:53.0 (19973023)|USER_DEBUG|[62]|DEBUG|AUD
12:50:53.0 (20006415)|USER_DEBUG|[63]|DEBUG|false
12:50:53.0 (20026344)|USER_DEBUG|[64]|DEBUG|1746277182
12:50:53.0 (20041304)|USER_DEBUG|[65]|DEBUG|608648681
12:50:53.0 (20068693)|USER_DEBUG|[62]|DEBUG|CAD
12:50:53.0 (20097827)|USER_DEBUG|[63]|DEBUG|false
12:50:53.0 (20116138)|USER_DEBUG|[64]|DEBUG|76325736
12:50:53.0 (20130603)|USER_DEBUG|[65]|DEBUG|608648681
12:50:53.0 (20157100)|USER_DEBUG|[62]|DEBUG|GBP
12:50:53.0 (20186003)|USER_DEBUG|[63]|DEBUG|true
12:50:53.0 (20204017)|USER_DEBUG|[64]|DEBUG|127990640
12:50:53.0 (20218331)|USER_DEBUG|[65]|DEBUG|608648681
```

As you can see in the last two lines, the enum equals true when testing directly against the `keyset()`.  However `containsKey()` returns `false` (USER_DEBUG|[58]);

Weird thing is... This definitely seems to work in other contexts.  I know I could easily work around this by using `enum.name()` as the key instead of the enum itself, but I really want know whats going on here.

### UPDATE 2:

I added `hashCode()` details and confirmed that they are different!  So basically it's possible for two enums of the same value to generate different Hash Codes!?

Comment: is there any way I can see how your map is formed?

Comment: @Rao, there's quite a bit of code involved because I'm pulling data from a Currency Exchange API.  I think the issue is the context.  This same function works as expected when running in a VF page or aynon apex.  

However, I'm getting this bug when running in a batch context.  The Map is initialized in the Batch Start method.  I'm going to do some more digging and see if I can replicate with a simpler use case

Comment: Maybe enum is being treated as Object instead. Can you try as passing the key: CurrencyType.GBP  ...........also trim the input parameter to make sure that there is no trailing space

Comment: @AyubAnsari I assume the op would have done the same, the class would not save unless its a CurrencyType member

Comment: @AyubAnsari, ya I've already tried passing the key directly in.  same result

Comment: @Rao See above... I was able to confirm that the hashcodes between two Identical enums did not match!!! this seems like a platform bug to me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.

In java, the [hashCode for an enum is not consistent across different executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435925/different-enum-hashcode-generation).

My Map is being initialized in the Batchable `start()` (with `Database.Stateful`).  Then I try to access the map in Batchable `execute()`.

Behind the scenes, salesforce must be running `start()` & `execute()` in separate java executions.  This means that when the hashcode is evaluated in the `start()` method it is not the same as when it is evaluated in the `execute()`

In short, Enums cannot be used as keys in when using `Database.Stateful`.

UPDATE:

I did some testing and it only seems to be an issue when you use a query locator and only fails on the second iterator.  I've replicated it with the following code:

```
global class BatchEnumTesting implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    public Enum Foo{
        A, B, C
    }


    private Integer i;
    private Map<Foo, String> enumMap;

    global BatchEnumTesting() {}

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        i = 1;

        enumMap = new Map<Foo, String>();
        enumMap.put(Foo.A,'Testing1');
        enumMap.put(Foo.B,'Testing2');
        enumMap.put(Foo.C,'Testing3');

        for(Foo e : Foo.values()){
            System.debug('Key: ' + e.Name()  + ' | ' + e.hashCode());
        }

        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Account Limit 2');
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
        System.debug(i++);

        for(Foo e : enumMap.keySet()){
            System.debug('Key: ' + e.Name());
            if(e == Foo.A){
                System.debug('Hash Compare: ' + e.hashCode() + ' | ' + Foo.A.hashCode());
                System.debug('Map Match : ' + enumMap.containsKey(Foo.A));
            }else if(e == Foo.B){
                System.debug('Hash Compare: ' + e.hashCode() + ' | ' + Foo.B.hashCode());
                System.debug('Map Match : ' + enumMap.containsKey(Foo.B));
            }if(e == Foo.C){
                System.debug('Hash Compare: ' + e.hashCode() + ' | ' + Foo.C.hashCode());
                System.debug('Map Match : ' + enumMap.containsKey(Foo.C));
            }
        }
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
```

Run with a batch size of 1:

```
Database.executeBatch(new BatchEnumTesting(), 1);
```

Comment: So finally- In short, Enums cannot be used as keys in when using Database.Stateful.....gonna remember that:)

Comment: I faced a similar issue with Map(string,object) passing b/w start and execute methods. I was trying to pass an object as a value with a string as a key and it somehow did not like it. So, to make it work, i had to pass the object as String, passing all the fields from that object concatenating them. Maps & Batchables have to be used with caution.

Comment: @ShaliniMendu very odd... I think it might have something to do with the fact that the state must be serialized to pass between executions.  Some objects are not serializable.

Comment: @NSjonas, true! The issue is when you code, you expect these things to work seamlessly and it takes an extra amount of time/analysis/effort to fix these issues.

Comment: @ShaliniMendu especially since this issue in particular will NEVER be caught by a failing unit test or even smaller manual tests (since it only fails when more than 1 batch is run)

Comment: I just spent 3 hours of my life discovering the same thing as I refused to consider this as a possibility until exhaustive debugging of all other options. Wouldn't you know that the answer was on SFSE. +1 for both question and answer